# Unable to test http cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have this simple code in my `index.js` file that will be deployed as cloud functions

```js
exports.getSubscriptionsPlans = functions.https.onRequest( async (req, res) => { 
    stripe.prices.list({
         lookup_keys: ['my_test_plan', 'my_test_plan_1'],
         expand: ['data.product']
    }).then( (prices) => {
       res.send(prices.data)
    })
    //res.send(prices.data)
})

exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {
    const email = data.email
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        email: email
    })
    return {
        customer: customer
    }
});
```

I want to use simple http cloud functions requests to manage stripe subscriptions in my vue app, but at the moment when I try to test the functions I get two errors.

The first one is related to the `getSubscriptionsPlan` and I have a `Error: could not handle the request` the second error is with the `createStripeCustomer` function that when I try to call using postman and passing the `email: example@axample.com` as body, it will give me this error `{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}`

What I'm doing wrong in the code and what's the correct way to proceed?

Comment: Your first function is declared as `async` but you use the `then()` method and not `await`. What happens if you remove the `async` keyword. For the second function , can you show how you call it (front end code)?

Comment: I recommend isolating the failure with logs before and after the calls to Stripe. For example, try logging `data.email` to ensure the cloud function is getting passed an email as a parameter. Follow that with a log of `customer` to observe what Stripe returns.

If Stripe throws any errors, contact https://support.stripe.com/contact with request details, https://support.stripe.com/questions/finding-the-id-for-an-api-request, and they can further troubleshoot.